# How to get a clean pagination link without variable

Tags: permalinks, pagination

This is my Code

```
if($totalPage > 1){
    $customPagHTML = paginate_links(
        array(
          'base' => add_query_arg( 'cp', '%#%' ),
          'format' => '',
          'prev_text' => __('Back', '&laquo;'),
          'next_text' => __('Next', '&raquo;'),
          'total' => $totalPage,
          'current' => $page,
          'type' => ''
        )
    );
}
echo $customPagHTML;
```

Link showing like that:- site.com/page/?cp=2

But I want to show it like : **site.com/page/cp/2** or **site.com/page/2**

Note: Getting result from custom db table

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM custom_table WHERE custom_table.id = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you retrieve link like `site.com/page/?cp=2`, because you added get parameter `cp`.

If you wanna link like `site.com/page/cp/2` - remove `base` parameter and set `format` to `?cp=%#%`

If you wanna link like `site.com/page/2` - remove 'base' and 'format' parameters and stay it default. Because `format` - is `?page=%#%` by default.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any extra work! Just remove the `format` and `base` parameter and you'll get URL in this format `site.com/page/2`. Btw, I've fixed your Back and Next translation.

```
if ( $totalPage > 1 ) {
    echo paginate_links(
        array(
            'prev_text' => __( 'Back &laquo;', 'text-domain' ),
            'next_text' => __( 'Next &raquo;', 'text-domain' ),
            'total'     => $totalPage,
            'current'   => $page,
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: `global $wpdb;
$customPagHTML = "";
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_tuk_wise_arth WHERE wp_tuk_wise_arth.ang_no = '$angno'";
$total_query     = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM wp_tuk_wise_arth WHERE wp_tuk_wise_arth.ang_no = '$angno'";
$total = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
$items_per_page = $tuk_per_page;
$page = isset( $_GET['cp'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cp'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );
$totalPage = ceil($total / $items_per_page);
 
foreach ($result as $post){

}`

Comment: that's the code to get query result now solve it.